# Please explain this Javascript quirk

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, variables

Someone I know is just learning programming and stumbled upon this and left me baffled:

Please open a console (Chrome/Firefox) and type: `var name = ['what', 'the', '...?'];`

I would expect `name` to be an array of strings, but:

- `typeof name` displays `string` instead of `Array`
- listing the `name` variable prints a string instead of an array
- `name.length` is `13` instead of `3`
- writing `name = name.split(',')` returns an array `["what", "the", "...?"]` as expected, but `name` is still a `string`, not an array

`name` is the only variable name that seems to behave this way, or at least I couldn't find another one.

Is this just a console quirk, a JavaScript engine bug, or what?

NOTE: the above happens on Chrome and Firefox. IE Edge surprisingly works as expected (`typeof name` is `Array` and all that). Not tested on other browsers.

Comment: Try using a variable name other than `name`. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/name

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[`window.name`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/name) is a global which is a string in the DOM.

Notice you can get around it by declaring the variable in a function scope:

```js
(function() {
   var name = ['foo', 'bar'];
   console.log(typeof name);
})();
```

As for why IE/Edge is different - its their interpretation of the spec and likely has been that way for years. Changing it now would be a breaking change.

Comment: so why in Edge that doesn't happen ?!!

Comment: Actually the default `window.name` seems to be a property with a setter that turns any value it's being assigned into a string. If you `delete window.name` then try again, you'll get an array as expected. 
@DanielA.White please update your answer to include this. Thanks :)